# Displaying Date in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How I should use `SELECT` command in SQL Server for displaying the date (on asp.net webform) from my `DATE` column in the database, in a format in which users want?

I have declared my date column as `DATETIME` type, saving default current date/time

UPDATE: I want to elaborate my question:

For example, I have a table `tbemployee` with columns `id`, `empName`, `Joining date`.

When I want to display the records on my web form, I write the SQL statement as:

```
SELECT * FROM tbemployee
```

it displays the record, but the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Now my question is: how can I display the date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format instead?

Comment: This is not clear. which date format you want?

Comment: anything other than the default one, actually i wanted to learn the way of writing the code in SELECT COMMAND

Comment: with default, i get e.g. like  5/14/2017 8:31:50 PM, now i for example want in format of dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Refer this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: @SankarRaj , i have updated the question, if you can help me plz., although i have searched the net, buttttt... of no use.

Answer (score 1):

You select query should be...

```
Select 
     id, 
     empName, 
     convert(varchar(15), [Joining date], 103) as [Joining date] 
from tbemployee
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL `Convert` function with your `JoiningDate` column to get the desired result.

Below is the SQL query which might help you.

```
Select 
ID,
EmpName,
convert(varchar(10),JoiningDate,103) as JoiningDate
from tbEmployee
```

Used Syntax: `CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)`

data_type(length): Specifies the target data type (with an optional length)
expression: Specifies the value to be converted
style: Specifies the output format for the date/time (see table below)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT GETDATE();
```

You can change formats: ymd, and so on.

Comment: I have updated the question. if you can help me, plz
thx in advance

Comment: Use SET DATEFORMAT DMY before select.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` in `[Joining date]` column.